# Will ngModel binding always precede change event?

Tags: angular

In the following example, the textbox has an associated ngModel binding as well a change function:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)] = "typedText" (change)="calculateTextLength()" />
```

In my limited experience, the "calculateTextLength()" function is called only after the input text has been updated in the "typedText" variable.

Can I know if there is a precedence order for these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To explain the process here, we should take some notes:

- `change` is not an “Angular event”, it’s a [DOM event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event).
- We can use `change` anywhere (not linked to Angular system).
- `change` will be fired when the user has blurred (~*leave*) the input (we are talking about DOM here not Angular)
- In Angular, and although it is not required to use `change` with `ngModel` in the same element (which not the case for Angular's `ngModelChange`), if we use them both, it will fire **after the value bound to `[(ngModel)]` has changed**

---

- There's an angularized version of `change` which is `ngModelChange`: an Angular event, it fires *when* (before) `ngModel` changes.
- We cannot user `ngModelChange` without `ngModel` (not the case for `change`)
- `ngModelChange` will only fire when the model is intended to be updated, i.e. essentially it is listening to the input event, and setting the model if a user types, pastes or changes the input’s value, that means : **will be fired before the value bound to `[(ngModel)]` has changed.**

[**Src & More details.**](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/difference-change-ngmodelchange-angular)

Answer (score 1):

First we need to understand that `(change)` is not an “Angular event”, it’s a DOM event.If you want dynamic binding you can use event called `(ngModelChange)` instead of `(change)`.I think that this should solve the issue.The order of attributes inside the tags doesn't matter but you can always rearrange them for better ease of understanding